# Open and close tabs based on array contents with delay

Tags: tabs, google-chrome-extension

I want to create new tabs based on the URL in an array, however in the process I need the script to wait for the page in the new tab to load first or wait a few seconds then close the tab and create a new tab after the first one closes.

Currently this code will create new tabs all at once and then the `close.js` script will close the tabs after a few seconds. So if I have 50 URLs in my array 50 new tabs will be created all at once, this is bad. I need the tabs to be created and closed one at a time not all at once.

I have tried using the `chrome.tabs.query` status parameter to solve this problem but this status parameter seems to only be relevant to the tab load status and not the page status.

Anyone have some ideas?

```js
var jsonObject = xhr.responseText;  
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonObject);
for (var i = 0; i < obj.url.length; i++) {
    chrome.tabs.create({"url":obj.url[i],"selected":false},function(tab){
        var createdTabId = tab.id;
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(createdTabId, {file: "js/close.js"});
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
var jsonObject = xhr.responseText;  
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonObject);
var timeout = 0;
var urlcount = 0;       

for (var i = 0; i < obj.url.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        chrome.tabs.create({"url":obj.url[urlcount],"selected":false},function(tab){
        var createdTabId = tab.id;
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(createdTabId, {file: "js/close.js"});
        }); 
        urlcount++;
    },timeout);  // put the timeout here
    timeout = timeout + 2000;
}
```